# boost logging fails to compile on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost, macports

trying to use Boost.Log on OSX (via MacPorts)

```
/*
 *          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2013.
 * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
 *    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 *          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */

#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;

//[ example_tutorial_trivial_with_filtering
void init()
{
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
//]
```

(code sample taken from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_trivial_flt.cpp)

but when compiling lot of unresolved externals errors are produced:

$ gcc -I/opt/local/include loggertest.cpp -o loggertest -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_log-mt

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name::attribute_name(char const*) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::auto_release::~auto_release() in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::~record_pump() in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::set_filter(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::filter const&)", referenced from:
      init() in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::push_record_unlocked(boost::rv<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record>&) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get()", referenced from:
      init() in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()", referenced from:
      _main in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::end() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name) const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-87632e.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::formatted_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::formatted_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::flush() in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::sentry::sentry(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::sentry::~sentry() in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in loggertest-87632e.o
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::exception in loggertest-87632e.o
      typeinfo for boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::type_info_wrapper::uninitialized in loggertest-87632e.o
      typeinfo for boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::visible_type<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> in loggertest-87632e.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)>::light_function<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > >(boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > const&, boost::disable_if_c<is_rv_or_same<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)> >::value, int>::type) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)>::impl<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > >::clone_impl(void const*) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)>::impl<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > >::destroy_impl(void*) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)>::light_function<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > >(boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > const&, boost::disable_if_c<is_rv_or_same<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)> >::value, int>::type) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_function<bool (boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&)>::impl<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::greater_equal, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_actor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, 0l> > >, 2l> > >::clone_impl(void const*) in loggertest-87632e.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-87632e.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-87632e.o
  "___cxa_rethrow", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-87632e.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      init() in loggertest-87632e.o
      _main in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::formatted_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::aligned_write(char const*, long) in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::~record_pump() in loggertest-87632e.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_severity_logger<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in loggertest-87632e.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

other boost libraries (system, thread, filesystem) work well. is there something wrong with my linker flags? build system? installation?

Edit: I also tried using clang++ as suggested, but I get similar errors:

$ clang++ -I/opt/local/include loggertest.cpp -o loggertest -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_log-mt -lboost_log_setup-mt

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name::attribute_name(char const*) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::auto_release::~auto_release() in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::~record_pump() in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(boost::exception&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::set_filter(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::filter const&)", referenced from:
      init() in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::push_record_unlocked(boost::rv<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record>&) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get()", referenced from:
      init() in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()", referenced from:
      _main in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::end() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set::find(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name) const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::value_extractor<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::fallback_to_none, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::tag::severity>::operator()(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_name const&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_value_set const&) const in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in loggertest-0b0a3b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Edit: solved by compiling with `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` as suggested by @neverpanic

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137637/linker-error-while-linking-boost-log-tutorial-undefined-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a standard library mismatch. Boost from MacPorts (and all other libraries from MacPorts and on modern OS X since 10.9, I think) are built against clang's libc++, rather than gcc's libstdc++. If you attempt to mix both standard libraries, you'll run into this problem (which is a good thing, because if you wouldn't see this, you'd likely see hard to debug crashes at runtime).

You need to use `clang++` instead of `gcc` to compile your code. Alternatively, you can use `/usr/bin/g++`, which is nowadays a symlink to clang.

Comment: I tried using clang++ or g++ (I updated original question including this result), but I get similar errors. (moreover, as I said, other boost libraries link fine)

Comment: You get similar errors, but not the same ones. You're now seeing a different problem that looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137637/linker-error-while-linking-boost-log-tutorial-undefined-references, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602943/g-static-link-error-against-boost-log, or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html. Try again with `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK`. Other boost libraries may have linked fine because none of their symbols used the `std` namespace in parameters, which gets mangled to `std::__1` when using `libc++`.